# Random 4 points(x,y) on a quadrangle, find the edge lengths?

Tags: python, math

I have 4 points on a quadrangle and i need the edge lengths,
but i couldn't find a way to determine the edges( i need a way to order the 4 points in a way which they denote a quadrangle. ) I am using python 2.7
NOTE=4 Points are not known, they will be given randomly to my program.I am asking how to denote a quadrangle that is to say will it be ABCD quadrangle or ACBD quadrangle etc. (Since ABCD might not denote a quadrangle too.It may denote an arbitraryquadrilateral)

Comment: "Programmers need highschool maths" - Pythagoras, 500 BC. `d = sqrt((x2 - x1) ^ 2 + (y2 - y1) ^ 2)`

Comment: Supposing two of your points are (x_0, y_0) and (x_1, y_1) respectively you can determine the length of the line which joins these points by applying Pythagoras's theorem; namely
L = sqrt((x_1 - x_0)^2 + (y_1 - y_0)^2)

Comment: I am sorry it was not what i wanted(sorry for my bad english) my program will be given 4 random points x1, x2, x3, x4 and i will use the edge lengths of the quadrangle but how can i write the quadrangle?( i may say x2, x1, x4, x3 quadrangle but it could also be an arbitraryquadrilateral)  I need an order of these 4 points in which they denote a quadrangle%100. i hope this makes sense!

Comment: I'm really having difficulty seeing what you want given your comment here and your edit - is there something special about your labeling since if you tell me you have an ABCD quadrangle, what changes if I relabel B as C such that it is now an ACBD quadrangle!??? ... please help us to help you here!

Comment: Thanks so much for your interest.4points in a plane represented in the 2-D coordinate system.
I need to determine whether these four points are on a circle.So i have found an algorithm in which i use the edge lengths of a quadrangle(those 4 points are on the corner of this quadrangle) I need a help to name this quadrangle. Example: a(1,3) b(1,0) c(3,0) and d(4,1)   if i say acdb quadrangle it will be wrong because  it doesnt denote a quadrangle. I need an algorithm which will order these 4 numbers in such a way that i can say abcd is an quadrangle for sure.Thanks in advance! !

Answer (score 0):

Order them according to x and y coordinates.

```
if p1.x<p2.x && p1.y<p2.y
    add to an array of points
...
```

just figure out a way to organize them by using a series of "if statements", then calculate the edge lengths using:

```
length = sqrt((x2 - x1) ^ 2 + (y2 - y1) ^ 2)
```

It should only take you a couple minutes to write this code yourself, still, let us know if you need help.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot and glad to see that you understood my question.I know how to find length but don't i have to know the name of the quadrangle to use the length formula.It says x2 -x1 but which x2 and which x1? Could you write it if its not too long please since i still cant use the length formula for i cant decide what to put for x1 and x2?

Comment: Program will enter a black-box test.Therefore, I can't see the internals (random points)